# How to access to the application through browser?

Tags: node.js, browser, web

How can I access my server through the browser once I've set up the server ?

In PHP I simply have to put my files in the www/ folder and then go to `http://127.0.0.1/index.php`, but how can I do that with NodeJS ?

My server's code is from a [tutorial](http://www.webdesignermag.co.uk/tutorials/build-a-web-server-with-node-js/) :

```
var app = require(‘express’).createServer();

app.get(‘/’, function(request, response){
    response.send(‘Hello Web Designer’);
});

app.listen(8888);
```

But whenever I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8888/` i get a "Problem loading the page". So either my server is not running correctly (hard to tell when the NodeJS console shows "...") or I am not accessing it correctly.

What can I do please ?

Comment: youre not using quotation marks ?

Comment: Where ? in the command line to run the server ?

Comment: in the code, you are using `‘` but need to use `"` or `'` did you change it before posting it?

Comment: Yeah i didn't see. Well i don't know, i always use '. Anyway if there was a mistake, it's gone since i'm using the code from one of the answers, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

you have to send a http head and end the response.

Try this code.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('hello world');
  res.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

(Pseudo Code)

Also don't use any frameworks to learn how node works.
You can run you index.js now and call localhost:8888

Comment: Yes that's what i did the first time, but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I have no index.js file yet. I tried to add index.js and server.js after :8888/ but it still doesn't work. Is there a way to know if my server is running correctly ?

Comment: Did you tried a different port? Btw. the name is not important, node just can detect the index file if you run a directory.

Comment: Okay I tried the exact code on top and it works fine for me. What version do you use

Comment: I donwloaded it yestarday so i assume it is v0.10.13
If it does work for you, then i probably don't start the server correctly. How can i be sure it runs ?

Comment: If you use my example an add the line console.log('Hello'); after the head, you will receive a message on your console every time someone is connecting. Just kick express out, this is a framework what is used for real projects but not for training. btw. try to use the node API http://nodejs.org/api/ there is everything in you need

Comment: I tried adding a console.log() but nothing appeared when i asked for the page. Do i have to place my server.js file in a specific folder ? Do i have to add a piece of path after :8888/ to access it ?

Comment: no, you add to you console $ node /path/to/server.js and this file contains my code on top. Now you should see a empty terminal where you can type stuff in. Also you can visit localhost:8888 you you will receive the response message, in this case 'hello world'.

Comment: Do i need to add the '$' too ?

Comment: No, was symbolic for the command line. Do you get a terminal after run you server.js

Comment: Firefox keeps saying : `Unable to connect Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8888.` when i try to visit that address, no matter if i use localhost or 127.0.0.1 or iif i add server.js or index.js or whatever

Comment: I get a prompt `...` where i can type stuff as you said, but it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Yes, but you get something ... what about debugging, delete the code and just leave a console.log('does it work?');. Now you should see 'does it work?' in you terminal.

Comment: Hmm, did you killed the process of node and run it again? It is not like apache start once use forever.

Comment: Well i did ctrl + C to get the prompt back, and run it again. I'm going to try closing the terminal. EDIT : still nothing

Comment: ctrl + c is just fine I do the same. But if you get nothing in the terminal, the path is wrong

Comment: Should i use a linux style path with / instead of C:\ and slashes instead of anti slashes ? I'm gonna try placing the file at the disk root.

Comment: I have no idea of windows sorry :D don't like it

Comment: Same result hehe. Also when i type the path without quotes i get a node is undefined error message.

Comment: if node is undefined you should check you registry

Answer (score 0):

Did you start the server? The apache server runs php, in the nodejs world, there is a javascript runtime that needs to be started.

Try `node server.js` from the command line (or whatever your file is called) to get it to listen and serve incoming requests.

Comment: I did it : `node 'C/Document and settings/users/virus/NodeJS/test_00/server.js'` EDIT Actually there was a mistake in the path, but it is still not working after i corrected it.